# How to prepend items in kendo mobile ui at listview. I am using kendo v2013.1.319

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have try this 
$("#divPostList").data("kendoMobileListView").prepend("...");

but it gives error prepend: *prepend is not a function*

Comment: We can append data using Load-More functionality but how can we prepend it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Prepend was not available in v2013.1.319.

Answer (score 1):

`prepend` method has an array as argument. You should use:

```
$("#divPostList").data("kendoMobileListView").prepend([ "..." ]);
```

But this is not available in v2013.1.319, Can you use the latest release? If you need to stay on v2013.1.319 you need to do something like:

```
// Get reference to the listview
var listview = $("#divPostList").data("kendoMobileListView");
// Get reference to the datasource
var ds = listview.dataSource;
// Get original data
var old = ds.data();
// New items + old
var prepended = $.merge([ "Prepended 1", "Prepended 2" ], old);
// Send prepended to listview
ds.data(prepended);
```

You can see it running here : http://dojo.telerik.com/@OnaBai/ONiY

But of course, upgrading Kendo UI version makes it much easier.